How can I force boost to throw a boost::filesystem::filesystem_error when running as root?
I have some code that can throw boost::filesystem::filesystem_error exceptions under certain (difficult to reproduce) situations.
I have exception handlers set up, and I'd like to test the correct behavior of the exception handlers.
If I'm not running as root, I can force these exceptions by opening a file in an inaccessible directory.
However, our build pipelines run the tests (for better or worse) as root, and in this case, the permission checks are bypassed and the exceptions are not thrown.
How can I force boost::filesystem to throw an exception when the code is running as root?

It depends on what kind of error you want to emulate. You can still easily mark things readonly, or create broken links etc. Otherwise, the real solution is to change the executing user.

This is not so much a question about boost or C++, but...
It depends on what your code is doing. If you're opening an existing file, but don't create it (because it's a data file that needs to be there, not a cache file or something), you can just not have it there.
If you're creating the file if it's not there, but not the directory it's in, remove the directory.
If you're creating the file and the directory, just create a file with the name of the directory -- most software won't delete the file to make room for the directory and instead just fail.
And so on. Look at what your software does, and find a spot to screw it up.

The code is pretty complicated and handles missing files & file open failures separately.
That being said, though, having a directory in the place of the target file might well do the trick.   I'll give that a try.
